# Генерации пути из шагов и прыжков (оптимизация алгоритма)

Tags: c++, алгоритм, разработка-игр, оптимизация

Игроку необходимо пройти из точки `start` в точку `end`. На каждой точке, он видит одну из двух инструкций:

1. Иди на следующую точку (адрес `текущий + 1` (NEXT))
2. Иди на указанную точку (адрес `[start + 1.. end - 1]` (JUMP))

Как случайным образом сгенерировать пути для игрока, что бы не было зацикленности?
Путь должен быть сгенерирован так, что бы игрок прошел все точки и что бы нельзя было спрогнозировать, куда будет прыжок (кроме последнего. Последний прыжок будет на последнюю область). Конечная точка должна иметь инструкцию NEXT.

[image: Схема передвижения игрока]

Параметр генератора `percent` - это отношение количества команд JUMP к количеству точек(1000). `precent = 100` означает, что все точки содержат инструкцию JUMP, кроме последней точки.

Посоветуйте как можно оптимизировать алгоритм? Мой алгоритм для генерации пути в 200'000 точек очень много времени занимает. А планируемая максимальная длина 1М точек.

1. Посчитать количество инструкций JUMP.
2. Разместить инструкции JUMP (без указывания адреса прыжка). Тогда
   начала сегмента будет следующий адрес после JUMP.
3. Назначить(соединить) случайным образом каждой команде JUMP адрес
   начала сегмента. Нельзя назначать уже с соединенным сегментом.
4. Сгенерировать путь.

У меня не особо получилось сделать алгоритм эффективным ни по времени, ни по памяти. Главнее сделать алгоритм эффективным по времени. Если есть идеи для улучшения, буду благодарен. Если можно распараллелить процесс, подскажите как.

Пример кода:

```
// seed - для псевдослучайности
void generatePath(int start, int end, double percent, uint seed = 1)
{
    QRandomGenerator randG(seed);
    const int lenPath = end - start + 1;
    // 1. Посчитать количество инструкций JUMP.
    const int cntJump = int((lenPath - 1) * percent);

    QVector<int> ggLenPath(lenPath-1);
    std::generate(ggLenPath.begin(), ggLenPath.end(), [n = -1] () mutable { return ++n; });

    // 2. Разместить инструкции JUMP (без указывания адреса прыжка).
    // Тогда начала сегмента будет следующий адрес после JUMP.
    QVector<int> jumpAddrSource(cntJump);

    std::sample(ggLenPath.begin(), ggLenPath.end(), jumpAddrSource.begin(), cntJump, randG);

    // 3. Назначить(соединить) случайным образом каждой команде JUMP
    // адрес начала сегмента. Нельзя назначать уже с соединенным
    // сегментом и на себя.
    QVector<int> jumpAddrDest = jumpAddrSource;
    {
        int currJump = 0;
        std::set<int> existsLink;
        for (int i = 0; i < cntJump - 1; ++i) {
            int numSector = randG.bounded(cntJump - 1 - i);
            int offset = 0;
            for (const auto &ex : existsLink) {
                if (numSector + offset >= ex) {
                    ++offset;
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
            existsLink.insert(numSector + offset);
            jumpAddrDest[currJump] = jumpAddrSource[numSector + offset] + 1;
            currJump = numSector + offset + 1;
        }
        jumpAddrDest[currJump] = jumpAddrSource[cntJump - 1] + 1;
    }
    // 4. Сгенерировать путь.
    for (int i = 0; i < lenPath; ++i) { addPointNext(i); }
    for (int i = 0; i < jumpAddrSource.size(); ++i) { addPointJump(jumpAddrSource[i], jumpAddrDest[i]); }
}
```

---

**UDP:** реализовал алгоритм @MBo на с++ (generatePathMbo). Результат:

```
generatePath(0, 200000, 1) =  304.713 sec // 99% времени занимает пункт 3 (наполнение jumpAddrDest)
generatePathMbo(0, 200000, 1) =  0.073 sec
```

Код:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QRandomGenerator>
#include <QVector>
#include <set>

const bool PRINT_GEBUG = true;

static QStringList ll;

void addPointNext(int address) {
    if (PRINT_GEBUG) {
        ll << QString("%1 - NEXT").arg(address, 4, 10, QLatin1Char('0'));
    }
}

void addPointJump(int address, int jumpAddr) {
    if (PRINT_GEBUG) {
        ll[address] = QString("%1 - JUMP : %2")
                .arg(address, 4, 10, QLatin1Char('0'))
                .arg(jumpAddr, 4, 10, QLatin1Char('0'));
    }
}

void generatePath(int start, int end, double percent, uint seed = 1); //код выше

void generatePathMbo(int start, int end, double percent, uint seed = 1)
{
    QRandomGenerator randG(seed);
    const int lenPath = end - start + 1;
    const int cntJump = int((lenPath - 1) * percent);

    QVector<int> path(lenPath - 1);
    std::generate(path.begin(), path.end(), [n = 0] () mutable { return ++n; });
    QVector<int> starts(cntJump + 1);
    starts[0] = 0;
    std::sample(path.begin(), path.end(), starts.begin() + 1, cntJump, randG);
    QVector<int> ends(cntJump);
    std::transform(starts.begin() + 1, starts.end(), ends.begin(), [] (int addr) { return --addr; });

    if (PRINT_GEBUG) {
        qDebug() << starts;
        qDebug() << ends;
    }

    for (int i = cntJump; i >= 2; --i) {
        int iFrom = randG.bounded(1, i);
        if (iFrom < i - 1) {
            std::swap(starts[iFrom], starts[i - 1]);
            std::swap(ends[iFrom], ends[i - 1]);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < lenPath; ++i) { addPointNext(i); }
    for (int i = 0; i < ends.size(); ++i) { addPointJump(ends[i], starts[i + 1]); }
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QElapsedTimer t;
    t.start();

    generatePath(0, 11, 0.4);
    qDebug() << "generatePath() = " << t.restart() / 1000. << "sec";
    if (PRINT_GEBUG) { for (const auto & l : ll) { qDebug() << l; } }
    ll.clear();
    generatePathMbo(0, 11, 0.4);
    qDebug() << "generatePathMbo() = " << t.restart() / 1000. << "sec";
    if (PRINT_GEBUG) { for (const auto & l : ll) { qDebug() << l; } }
    ll.clear();
    return a.exec();
}
```

**Out:**

```
generatePath() =  0 sec
"0000 - JUMP : 0004"
"0001 - JUMP : 0002"
"0002 - NEXT"
"0003 - JUMP : 0011"
"0004 - NEXT"
"0005 - NEXT"
"0006 - NEXT"
"0007 - NEXT"
"0008 - NEXT"
"0009 - NEXT"
"0010 - JUMP : 0001"
"0011 - NEXT"
QVector(0, 1, 2, 4, 11)
QVector(0, 1, 3, 10)
generatePathMbo() =  0.011 sec
"0000 - JUMP : 0002"
"0001 - JUMP : 0004"
"0002 - NEXT"
"0003 - JUMP : 0001"
"0004 - NEXT"
"0005 - NEXT"
"0006 - NEXT"
"0007 - NEXT"
"0008 - NEXT"
"0009 - NEXT"
"0010 - JUMP : 0011"
"0011 - NEXT"
```

Comment: Первая мысль, рассматривать все шаги как прыжки, просто некоторые из них на адрес +1, а остальные - нет. Вторая мысль начать с массива заполненного прыжками на +1 и перемешать его (обновляя указатели).

Comment: Прыжок не должен выполняться на ту клетку где игрок уже побывал, иначе будет цикл. Насчет алгоритма: мы можем разделить всю карту на сегменты и с помощью jump соединить их

Comment: Задача крайне жестоко недоопределена. По сути нет никаких исходных данных - ну и как её, такую, решать?

Comment: @Akina каких исходных данных не хватает?

Comment: Вот тебе простейший алгоритм заполнения, соблюдающий ВСЕ поставленные условия. *Если условия разрешают хотя бы один прыжок (percent > 0) - в точку 0 помещаем JUMP 1000, всё остальное заполняем от фонаря. Если прыжков ноль - все точки содержат NEXT.* Ну и как, устраивает?

Comment: Вот тебе другой алгоритм. *Заполняем случайно, JUMP из любой точки делаем строго на точку с бОльшим номером.* Устраивает?

Comment: @Akina необходимо пройти все все точки. А на счет Jump на следующий адрес - в целом это формально решение задачи и да это я не все условия написал. Хочется что бы нельзя было спрогнозировать куда будет прыжок (кроме последнего. Он будет прыгать на последнюю область).

Comment: Вот-вот... вот ВСЁ это - добавляйте в свой вопрос. И всё остальное, что Вы сочли "несущественным".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Простая реализация идеи @trollingchar, пример на Python.

Задаётся длина и количество прыжков.

Путь path содержит номер ячейки, в которую переходим из текущей. Данная реализация не отслеживает, чтобы не было прыжков на +1, аналогичных простому переходу, поэтому возможна выдача пути типа `[1,2,3,4,5]`

Списки `starts` и `ends` хранят начала и концы интервалов, начало первого всегда 0, последнего N-1

Начиная с последнего интервала, прицепляем к его началу конец случайно выбранного (кроме первого). Передвигаем этот выбранный на последнее место, подлежащее обработке (чтобы больше его не трогать), и на следующей итерации уже к его началу цепляем следующий случайный из тех, что стоят в списке раньше.

Для пути длиной в миллион с 200 тыс. прыжков работает секунду на Python, так что на С++ будет в сто раз быстрее, и можно попробовать добавить запреты прыжков из предыдущего интервала.

```
import random
def genpath(N, jmps):
    path = [(i + 1) for i in range(N - 1)]
    starts = [0] + random.sample(range(1, N), jmps)
    starts.sort()
    ends = [(starts[i + 1] - 1) for i in range(jmps)] + [N-1]
    print(starts)
    print(ends)
    for i in range(jmps, 1, -1):
        ifrom = random.randrange(1, i)
        path[ends[ifrom]] = starts[i]
        if ifrom < i - 1:
            starts[ifrom], starts[i-1] = starts[i-1], starts[ifrom]
            ends[ifrom], ends[i-1] = ends[i-1], ends[ifrom]
    path[ends[0]] = starts[1]
    return path

print(genpath(20, 6))

[0, 3, 4, 6, 9, 10, 14]  starts
[2, 3, 5, 8, 9, 13, 19]  ends 
[1, 2, 10, 6, 5, 14, 7, 8, 9, 4, 11, 12, 13, 3, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]  path
```

Comment: не понял что происходит в цикле. У вас параметр `jmps` равен `6`. А результирующий путь получился с девятью прыжками.

Comment: `1,2,10==>11,12,13,3==>6==>7,8,9=>4==>5,14==>15,16,17,18,19` 6 прыжков, один из них на +1 (9=>4)

Comment: Спасибо. Для 2М на `с++` выполняет за `0.884 sec`, на `python = 8.5703367000 sec`.